# Adding and representing chars with asterisk in java

Tags: java, chars

I have this assignment where I need to create a program that reads the user input and reads the sentence and in the end it needs to represent the amount of times each char repeats itself with asterisk.

By this time this is all the code I have for this assignment:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Chars {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("insere um texto");
    String teutexto = teclado.nextLine();
    int a = 0;
    for(int x=0;x<teutexto.length();x++){
        if( String.charAt(0) == 'a'){

        }

    }
```

Comment: In advance of what? Closevotes? We expect an effort from your part.

Comment: We won't write code for you. If you've tried - show us what you've written so far and what specific problems you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way of doing it using bucket sort. You simply keep an array of integers for each character in the alphabet and increase them each time the character occurs in the input string.

We know that `(int)'a' = 97`, `(int)'b' = 98` etc. So a little trick to represent `(a,b,...,z)` as `(0,1,...,25)` is to set that for a given character `ch` that `(int)(ch-'a')`. Thus we subtract the value of `ch` with `97`. For example: `(int)('a'-'a') = 0` and `(int)('z'-'a') = 25`.

Now we can easily make an array `int[] occurrences = new int[26]` where `occurrences[i]` will be the number of occurrences of the i-th character in the alphabet.

For example in the string `"aaab"`, after running the algorithm:

`occurrences[0] = 3` and `occurrences[1] = 1`.

This is the same as

`occurrences['a'-'a'] = 3` and `occurrences['b'-'a'] = 1`

If you understand this concept, you will see that we can simply loop through the input string and for each character `ch` we can just increase `occurrences[ch-'a']++`. This is the whole algorithm.

**Here is the full code:**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

int[] occurrences = new int[26];

// go through all the characters in the input string
for(char ch : str.toCharArray())
    if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') // 'ch' is a valid character in the alphabet
        occurrences[ch-'a']++; // increase the occurrence of 'ch'

// go through the the alphabet
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    System.out.print((char)('a'+i) + ": "); // print the i-th character in the alphabet
    // occurrences[i] contains the number of occurrences of the i-th character
    for(int j = 0; j < occurrences[i]; j++)
        System.out.print("*"); // print '*' for every occurrance of the i-th character
    System.out.println(); // separate with new line
}
input.close(); // close scanner
```

Comment: thank you for clearing my questions. i will review it until i completely understand it

Comment: @user3002929 I edited it. More detailed explanation now!